# How/Where to find a T4 Template that Change behavior of creating View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I am interested in finding a T4 template that change a view generator and add some radio buttons and control grouping between Model properties, I read about it in [Scott Hanselman Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog) but I can't find it, is there any one to help me about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Hanselman: Modifying The Default Code Generation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

and [Hanselman: Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips-by-Scott-Hanselman)

Answer (score 2):

Install [Mvc3CodeTemplatesCSharp](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3CodeTemplatesCSharp) or [Mvc3CodeTemplatesVB](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3CodeTemplatesVB) via Nuget. That will add default t4 templates that asp.net mvc uses for generating views to your project. And then you can change those templates. Read more about that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/01/06/add-the-asp-net-mvc-3-code-templates-to-your-application-with-nuget.aspx)

```
PM> Install-Package Mvc3CodeTemplatesCSharp
```